# Marketing PC/Android 2d Physics Game

Tags: android, game-design, box2d, marketing, advertisements

I've been working on a game for couple years now, its fairly original, has definite potential within an indie market, and appeal for the masses also.

I want to deploy on Android and PC, green-light it on steam and looking into Kickstarter. I'm also going to set up a website where it can be played, have a dedicated server to link 'matches' and post demos on sites like mofunzone and armorgames.

I've used Jbox2d, and am also curious about the licencing with this engine and can't seem to find documentation on that.

I'm almost done the 'demo' and my question is, how should I market it?

I was thinking I'd make the game free on android, charge something like $10 on steam, and charge say 1$ month to play online (for the pc version)

If anyone has any good links, research or advice from personal experience, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you make the game free on android and let PC users pay $10 + $1/month?

The big trend for most indies is building a fanbase as soon you have something to show from your game. Blogging about everything that involves your game and perhaps let your fans influence your design.

You can find a lot of sources at open indie developers like Grid Sage Games. They just released there game Cogmind two month's ago and started blogging about it in [September 2013](http://www.gridsagegames.com/blog/2013/09/cogmind-returns/). They just released [sales information](http://www.gridsagegames.com/blog/2015/06/releasing-commercial-ascii-roguelike-post-mortem/) less then a month ago and you see that a fan base can greatly impact your initial sales. But not every game fits the bill to create a dedicated fan-base like Cogmind.

There are some great articles on [gamedev.net](http://www.gamedev.net), two new ones talk about [launching your game](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/business/business-and-law/3-steps-to-mastering-your-game%E2%80%99s-soft-launch-r4127) and [analytics](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/business/business-and-law/15-metrics-all-game-developers-should-know-by-heart-r4121). Perhaps the best thing to know is [how not to do it](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/business/business-and-law/how-not-to-market-your-indie-game-r3400). There is basically a ton of information laying around.

Good luck with your games launch!